# How to change the ValueToCompare in CompareValidator by javascript?

Tags: javascript, comparevalidator

In my form, there are password field, so that I cannot use postback.
I need to validate everything in client side.

But the ValueToCompare may change by the user input.

How to change the ValueToCompare in CompareValidator by javascript?

Thanks.

---

Maybe I need to tell the full case.
I have two input, said a & b, the sum of this two number cannot greater than c.

For example, 
c is 90
a is inputted 30, then b cannot be greater than 60.
if b is then entered to 40, than a cannot be greater than 50.

I am now doing this in server side, how can I do it in client side by using asp.net validations?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="valOptionsCmp" runat="server"
     ErrorMessage="!!!"
     ControlToValidate="tbPrixOptions" Display="Dynamic"
     ValueToCompare="1"
     Operator="GreaterThanEqual"
     Type="Integer"/>

//in javascript
<%=valOptionsCmp.ClientID%>.valuetocompare = yourvalue
```

Answer (score 0):

From:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx

Compares the value entered by the user in an input control with the value entered in another input control, or with a constant value.

Those are your choices.  Compare two controls, or compare one against a constant.

If neither suits, you may need to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you means something like **Enter Your Password** and **Please Reenter Password** type of comparison then you don't need to use **ValueToCompare**. Instead you use **ControlToCompare** and **ControlToValidate** like this:

```
  <asp:TextBox id="password" runat="server" TextMode="password"/>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="rfvPass" runat="server" 
   ControlToValidate="password" Text="*"/>

  <asp:textbox id=="rePassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"/>
  <asp:CompareValidator id="cmpPass" runat="server" ControlToCompare="password" 
   ControlToValidate="rePassword" Type="String" Operator="Equal"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problems with firebug helps:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("select[id$=ddlYears]").change(function() {
              var year= $(this).val(); 

              <%= cvDataMinApertura.ClientID%>.valuetocompare = "01/01/"+year;          

            });
        });
    </script>
```

I use JQuery for change compare validator cvDataMinApertura on change of years drop down list.